# Spring Formatter for Phone-number registered in different countries

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, formatter, libphonenumber

I have a task of phone number-formating for different countries.
For this aim I use libphonenumber. For example, I use the following code:

```
 phoneNumberProto = PhoneNumberUtil.parse(inputPhoneNumber, shortCode);
 String formattedPhoneNumber = phoneUtil.format(phoneNumberProto, 
 PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
```

And I'm considering using Formatter-annotation with this lib.
But the documentation says that Locale-parameter in Formatter.parse-method is the "the current user locale".

Does it mean, that I can use Formatter for only user-locale phones, not for any locales?
Otherwise, I have to create my own annotation?

Comment: Since there is no text in a phone number, the `Locale` is unused, i.e. will not affect parse result.

Comment: text is present.  Phone number in String-format.  It must parse, for example, number "0-101-456-34-23"  for "Germany" or "USA" or any other country

Comment: Sorry, I meant that there are no words (text) in a phone number, only digits and symbols (e.g. `-`, `(`, `)`, `+`). The `parse` method takes a `Locale`, so language-dependent parsing is possible, e.g. a date may spell out the month (January) or the day-of-week (Monday), so to parse that, the language needs to be known by the parser. Phone numbers don't have that, so doesn't need the `Locale`, and hence the parser should simply ignore that parameter.

Comment: Thank you - Its clearly now. So I cant use Formatter for my aim?

Comment: Why not? Which part of me saying that it should simply *ignore* the `Locale` parameter confused you?

Comment: Thank you, Andreas! Its clearly now. I followed your advice and apply Formatter for this aim. But have some problems with this way. Would you kindly to look my new question in    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60263162/spring-custom-formatter-to-field-annotation-does-not-work