# Spring custom formatter to field annotation does not work

Tags: java, spring, formatting, spring-annotations, formatter

I'm trying to apply formatter-annotation to the field "phone" in next model-class:

```java
public class User {
    @ContactNumberFormate
    private String phone;
}
```

Interface for annotation:

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ContactNumberFormate {
}
```

Formatter:

```java
@Component
public class PhoneFormatter implements Formatter<String> {

    @Override
    public String parse(String phoneNum, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        phoneNum = phoneNum.trim();
        String regex = "^\\(?(\\+*1)?[-.\\s*]?([0-9]{3})\\)?[-.\\s*]?([0-9]{3})[-.\\s*]?([0-9]{4})$";
        Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(phoneNum);

        return phoneNum;
    }

    @Override
    public String print(String phone, Locale locale) {
        return phone;
    }
}
```

Annotation-factory:

```java
public class PhoneFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory implements 
           AnnotationFormatterFactory<ContactNumberFormate> {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes() {
        return Collections.singleton(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Printer<?> getPrinter(ContactNumberFormate contactNumberFormate, Class<?> aClass) {
        return new PhoneFormatter();
    }

    @Override
    public Parser<?> getParser(ContactNumberFormate contactNumberFormate, Class<?> aClass) {
        return new PhoneFormatter();
    }
}
```

FormatterRegistrar:

```java
public class ApplicationFormatterRegister implements FormatterRegistrar {
    @Override
    public void registerFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry) {
        formatterRegistry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new PhoneFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory());
    }
}
```

config:

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">

    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>

</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="applicationConversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="formatterRegistrars">
        <set>
            <ref bean="applicationFormatterRegistrar"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="applicationFormatterRegistrar" class="ru.spb.dreamwhite.util.phoneUtil.ApplicationFormatterRegister"/>
```

And it does not work: phone-values saved in database, but in non-formatted form.

Note: when I run test in debug with breakpoint on PhoneFormatter, test passes susseccfully. That means, that my Formatter is out of process. But when I set breakpoint on `PhoneFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory.getFieldTypes`, test interrupted.

In particular, debug with breakpoint on `return Collections.singleton(String.class);` in

```java
public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes() {
    return Collections.singleton(String.class);
}
```

shows that the class `PhoneFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory` has no fields...

Comment: What is the purpose of this line: `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(phoneNum);`? You're not doing anything with the returned `Matcher`. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: I have not fully immersioned in realisation of formatter-method. Now I see, that my application does not see my formatter-annotation with any realisation...